# Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 3 arrays

Tags: python, input, keras

im working on a sentiment analaysis project with  keras since im new to keras i don't have any view to solve this problem:
this is my keras model

```
       model = Sequential()

      model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same', 
      input_shape=(15, 512)))
      model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same'))
      model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same'))
      model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same'))
      model.add(Dropout(0.25))
      model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
      model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
      model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
      model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
      model.add(Dropout(0.25))
      model.add(Flatten())
      model.add(Dense(256, activation='tanh'))
      model.add(Dense(256, activation='tanh'))
     model.add(Dropout(0.5))
     model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

   ......preprocessing for new input.....

  pred = model.predict(np.array(final))
  print("%s sentiment; %f%% confidence" % (labels[np.argmax(pred)], pred[0] 
  [np.argmax(pred)] * 100))
```

****assume final as an input
and when i want to predict the sentiment of an input, i face this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that 
you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to 
see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 3 arrays: [array([[ 
0.08031651,  0.05684812,  0.22872323, ..., -0.19047852
```

sorry if its such a stupid question! I know it was asked several times in the SOF but I did most of their suggestion, seems it was not practical to me since my poor knowledge about kras

thanks a lot

Comment: Well... your input data should be "one" array. Not three arrays. The problem is in `fit` or `predict` or similar methods.

Comment: You're going wrong while preparing your data. Could you please add some code of data preparation?

Comment: @VikasNS used this code [link](https://www.bonaccorso.eu/2017/08/07/twitter-sentiment-analysis-with-gensim-word2vec-and-keras-convolutional-networks/) and added pieces of codes for prediction,after some preprocessing step for the input sentence the rest of my prediction code is : _italic_ **bold** ' words = nltk.word_tokenize(evalSentence)
for word in words:
    if word in X_vecs:
        final.append(X_vecs[words])
       print("i find your vocab")
   
pred = model.predict(np.array(final))                                                                 X-vec related to my gensim model

Comment: @VikasNS I know there might be something related to my fit or prediction,but i don't have any idea to fix it! my input shape is 15 and when i get a sentence with the length 15 everything is ok, but if i change the input to 3 length for example, i face new  error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (15, 512) but got array with shape (3, 512) ***512 is my window_size in word2vec

Comment: @DanielMöller i know but i don't have any idea to fix it

Comment: Could you please add your full code to this question itself. I'm finding it hard to understand the link your code and the one in that link. So, could you please do me a favour by adding the code here itself?

Comment: @VikasNS i added the full code from the site that i metioned before with my extra code for prediction-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your code, add this code after the code present in that link

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
import numpy as np


vector_size=512
padding=np.zeros((vector_size ))
sentences=['im so happy','you are beautiful','i got scolded today']

final=[]
for sentence in sentences:
    temp=[]
    words=word_tokenize(sentence)
    for word in words:
        if word in X_vecs:
            temp.append(X_vecs[words])

    #padding to get length of 15
    for i in range(15-len(temp)):
        temp.append(padding)
    final.append(temp)



predictions = model.predict(np.array(final))

for prediction in predictions:
    print("%s sentiment; %f%% confidence" % (labels[np.argmax(prediction)], prediction[np.argmax(prediction)] * 100))
```

Could you please run this and report me back? If it works, I'll explain the code.

Comment: thanks for your attention, i run it with your sample and here is my error:   ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 1)

Comment: sure, this is the line error: predictions = model.predict(np.array(final))   seems it's related to predict

Comment: I made a small change, try now.

Comment: thanks alot- i faced new error IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.  i've been trying to fix it

Comment: i think the last error related to the second part of my last command i mean:  print("%s sentiment" % (labels[np.argmax(prediction)], prediction[0][np.argmax(prediction)] * 100)) so when i remove '''''''prediction[0][np.argmax(prediction)] * 100''''''(since im new to python) the problem was solved and print 3 times "negative" as  output,although we have 2 positive n 1 negative sentences it shows that the previous error was solved am i right?

Comment: Try for more examples. Let's see if it does well then.

Comment: sure. and i want to know that isn't any problem with my input shape?? is there any method to reshape it before getting new input? as i mentioned before my input shape is 15 and my model just accept input with the length of 15 - so i think maybe there are something wrong with inputshape

Comment: I have updated the code, now you must not get any errors.

Comment: Your model is expecting inputs of length 15, if you want to use inputs with less than 15 words, then you have to pad it. My code is doing it if you closely observe.

Comment: i just want to say thank you for your attention and sharing your creative solutions, the problem seems to be solved!! but unfortunately, with wrong sentiment, i want to know if it is related to poor examples or not, thanks a milion

Comment: I think the problem is that we have trained on long sentences, but we are testing on short sentences. So try testing on long sentences.

Comment: One more problem could be most of the words we are testing on may not be present in X_vecs. So we are mostly ending up with just paddings which is causing the wrong answer. So if the testing word is not present in X_vecs, you could just refrain from predicting as the possibility of the prediction being wrong is very high in that case.

Comment: aha, i know what you mean,,,i just thought if the problem related to padding method,,, i gonna adjust your code to my original code with strong corpus-hope it will work- i will report my result soon. thanks alooot

Comment: Hi Vikas NS, I still struggle with that error although I try to use your solution, do you have any idea to solve it?? this is my error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 15)